# Creating custom input text in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, geolocation, search

What is the best way to modify the searchbox listener [searchbox](http://screencast.com/t/EwVp0fZXgJh8) in the CartoDB map?

I would like to disable the default event listener for the CartoDB searchbox and first to execute my own listener and then decide If I want to execute the default CartoDB event (geolocation) for the searchbox.

How is the best way to do it?

I this is not possible can I add a second input text box in the map?

For now I am using  $(".cartodb-map-wrapper").append(' '); but I don't know if this is the best thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the funcitonality of the Searchbox. In the following example, I attach the ', British Columbia, Canada' text to it by default.

You can check the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/05e6feec84f12ab362df

Copying it also here for the record:

```
<script>

  cdb.geo.ui.Search = cdb.geo.ui.Search.extend({

    _submit: function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      var self = this;
      var address = this.$('input.text').val() + ', British Columbia, Canada';

      // Show geocoder loader
      this._showLoader();

      cdb.geo.geocoder.NOKIA.geocode(address, function(coords) {
        if (coords.length>0) {
          var validBBox = true;

          // check bounding box is valid
          if(!coords[0].boundingbox || coords[0].boundingbox.south == coords[0].boundingbox.north ||
            coords[0].boundingbox.east == coords[0].boundingbox.west) {
            validBBox = false;
          }

          if (validBBox && coords[0].boundingbox) {
            self.model.setBounds([
              [
                parseFloat(coords[0].boundingbox.south),
                parseFloat(coords[0].boundingbox.west)
              ],
              [
                parseFloat(coords[0].boundingbox.north),
                parseFloat(coords[0].boundingbox.east)
              ]
            ]);
          } else if (coords[0].lat && coords[0].lon) {
            self.model.setCenter([coords[0].lat, coords[0].lon]);
            self.model.setZoom(10);
          }
        }

        // Hide geocoder loader
        self._hideLoader();
      });
    }
  });


</script>
```